# Lighthill explanation of delta function/generalized functions

Tags: reference-request, definition, dirac-delta

I am reading Jaynes' "probability theory: the logic of science" which refers at one point to Dirac's delta function an example of a so called "generalized function".

Jaynes then says that "*mathematicians thinking in terms of the **set theory definition** of a 'function'*" considered delta-functions non-rigorous.

He explains how Lighthill justifies delta-functions/generalized functions using a different basis than set theory.

**My question is**: What is a good resource on (or could you explain) how to define functions in this non-set-theory way of Lighthill, and how the delta function is justified on the basis of it?

I am not very familiar with Fourier Analysis.

Here is the entire section in Jayne's book, in case it helps:

[image]

Comment: That statement *always* rubbed me the wrong way. Since we can always consider $\infty$ to be an object of the ambient mathematical universe (while not being a real number), there is absolutely no problem with the definition of the $\delta$-function as a set theoretic function. Once again ignorance in set theory lead to ridiculous claims about the limits of set theoretic foundations. *Sigh.*

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Well, the problem is that even if you define the $\delta$-function as taking a value $\infty$, that is not enough to usefully describe it.  For instance, you want $2\delta$ to be different from $\delta$.  You also want to be able to talk about the derivative $\delta'$.  Overall, there are a lot of things you want to do with the $\delta$-function that cannot be conveniently done by treating it as an object that has no more data than the values it takes at points.

Comment: Of course, it is ridiculous to call this a problem with "set theory"--it is just an issue with the notion of "function" being used in this context.

Comment: @Eric: You're right, of course. Just having $\infty$ is not enough to characterize the $\delta$-function, but it is often a complaint about its domain and codomain, etc, being "incomplete" in that sense. Which is why I made that comment.

Comment: The statements in Jaynes, particularly the criticism of Schwartz ("he persisted in defining the word 'function' in a way inappropriate to analysis"), suggest to me that it's better to pay no attention to his book. Analysis is what analysts do.  Analysts like Schwartz (Fields Medalist) and Hörmander (ditto) used the old, "inappropriate" concept of function.  While there may be other ways of constructing a theory of distributions/generalized functions, Schwartz's way has prevailed.

Comment: Looking briefly at Lighthill, he presumes the normal definition of function, defines a class of "good functions" which seems to me sort of like what is usually called $\cal{S}$, and then defines a generalized function as an equivalence class of sequences $f_n$ of "good" functions which converge in the sense that $\int f_n F$ converges for all "good" functions $F$; two sequences $f_n$ and $g_n$ are equivalent if $\lim_n \int f_n F=\lim_n\int g_n F$ for all "good" functions $F$.

Comment: @ForgotALot that sounds like the way I was taught distributions in my analysis class. I thought that was the original construction by Schwartz though?

Comment: @s.harp No, Schwartz took a space of test functions with a suitable topology, and defined the space of [corresponding] distributions as the topological dual of that. Taking the space $\mathscr{D}(M)$ of smooth functions with compact support on a manifold $M$ yields the space of (all) distributions on $M$, taking the space $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of rapidly decreasing functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ gives the tempered distributions (this is appropriate for Fourier theory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For references try:
"Delta Functions: Introduction to Generalized Functions", R.F. Hoskins;
"Mathematics for the Physical Sciences", Laurent Schwartz;
"Generalized Functions vol 1", I.M. Gelfand, G. E. Shilov.
The last 2 are classics in the areas of generalized functions and distributions.

But basically $δ(x)$ or $δ(x-a)$ is defined by

$$f(0)=\int f(x)δ(x)dx$$

or

$$f(a)=\int f(x)δ(x-a)dx ,$$

Where f is adequately well behaved.  Either suffices.  So δ(.) is usually defined by its action under the integral sign. Sometimes, in addition, its value is given as zero everywhere except at the single point, a, where its value is infinity, but this may not be needed.

However there are problems with this definition since a value at a single point should not change the value of an integral. So instead sometimes a 'inner product' notation is used

$$f(a) = (f(x) , δ(x-a)) $$

or

$$f(a) = <f(x) , δ(x-a)> $$

which transforms $f(x)$ to $f(0)$, or $f(x)$ to $f(a)$  --see Gelfand p4 or Schwartz p77,

Also it is better to use the terms 'Delta Distribution' or 'Dirac Delta' since $δ(x-a)$ is not properly a function.